# Problems allowing contributor to issue pull request

Tags: git, github

I'm relatively new to GitHub and the Git flow.

I'm working on a project where I would like to be the reviewer and have a contributor who issues pull requests for me to review.

So far my contributor:

1. Forked my repo to his account
2. Created a clone of the forked repo to his PC
3. Created a new branch containing updates to the code. He can push this branch with code via: git push upstream contributor-created-branch-w-updates. Note: Upstream is a remote that connects the clone in the contributors' PC (from the fork) with the original repo on my GitHub account.

Step three generates a push notification on my account (the reviewer). But then only I can create the pull request, given that the option only appears on my account. We tried having the contributor update his fork with the "contributor-created-branch-w-update" branch and then try to issue a pull request from his fork onto my (the original) repo. However, after trying to push his branch to his own fork (via git push origin contributor-created-branch-w-update) he gets an error: fatal: The current branch contributor-created-branch-w-update has no upstream branch.

How can I have my contributor issue the pull request for me to then review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, after trying to push his branch to his own fork (via git push origin contributor-created-branch-w-update) he gets an error: fatal: The current branch contributor-created-branch-w-update has no upstream branch.

Because he did that wrong. He left out the `-u`.

```
git push -u origin branch
```

Then the user can push, and now on GitHub the user will see the interface for opening a pull request with you.

Comment: Question: doesn't cloning a repo automatically configure the repo you cloned as a remote called 'origin'?

Comment: Yes but this is a new branch. It has to be associated with `origin`. That doesn’t happen all by itself.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe for me to be clear: should I be setting up my two remotes (origin and upstream) every time I create a a new branch?

Comment: Why would _you_ have two remotes? You are the owner of the original repo. It is your `origin`. It is this _other_ person who might have two remotes, but doesn't need to, because his `origin`, the fork, can submit pull requests to you.

Comment: Thank you. Good point. I just got confused. If I can ask, what does the "-u" do and why is it needed?

Comment: Also, my collaborator tried <git push -u origin new_branch>. The error I reported in the original post is not there and at first glance it seems to have work, that is, the edits were pushed to his repo. However, nothing is ever pushed. The message he gets is "Branch 'new_branch' set up to track remote branch 'new_branch' from 'origin'.

Comment: That message implies that all is well. Use `git status` to be sure. .

Comment: Thank you @matt. The changes were there but, obviously, under new_branch not master.

Comment: Yep, you do have to know how to actually _see_ what's going in GitHub. :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know that would be done like this:

- the other person forks your repo into their repo (in github)
- they push changes into a branch on their github repo
- Then they create a pull request into *your* repo from their forked repo branch.

And given that it is *your* repo, you are the only one in control deciding what gets merged and what doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. My problem seems to be related to second bullet you mention. If I may ask, how would you typically manage a situation where a collaborator pushing changes into a branch on their github repo but then their pull request into my repo gets rejected. What's the best way to proceed for the collaborator to avoid him working on code that won't be taken onboard?